# How to know external ip address of ansible client

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

During deployment needed setup ufw firewall rule: enable access for hosts group `servers` from inventory. Target host is anazon ec2 instance, but it maybe placed at other provider.

I tried:

```
- name: Ufw rules
  ufw: rule=allow from_ip={{ hostvars[item]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
  with_items: groups['servers']
  notify: 
    - Restart ufw
```

file `hosts`:

```
..
[servers]
server1.site.com
server2.site.com
server3.site.com
..
```

But host `server1.site.com`, actually have host_vars:

```
"ansible_eth0": {
   "active": true, 
   "device": "eth0", 
     "ipv4": {
        "address": "10.x.x.x", 
         ...
```

Ip address 10.x.x.x, as I understand, is internal amazon network ip address.

If execute `ping server1.site.com` from outside ec2, I get:

```
64 bytes from server1.site.com (46.x.x.x): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=49.5 ms
...
```

Executing `ansible server1.site.com -m setup -i hosts | grep 46.x.x.x` found nothing.

How to known external ip address of host from inventory group using ansible?
Or how setup ufw firewall using host names from inventory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use the lookup plugin written by @dsedivec (https://github.com/dsedivec/ansible-plugins).

Create a `lookup_plugins/` directory at the top directory of your playbook.
Put `dns.py` in it

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dsedivec/ansible-plugins/master/lookup_plugins/dns.py > lookup_plugins/dns.py
```

And use it like so :

```
- name: Ufw rules
  ufw: rule=allow from_ip={{ lookup('dns', item) }}
  with_items: groups['servers']
  notify: 
    - Restart ufw
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add connection: local

```
---
 - name: get my public IP
   ipify_facts: api_url=http://api.ipify.org
   connection: local

 - firewalld: rich_rule='rule family=ipv4 source address={{ ipify_public_ip }} accept' permanent=no state=enabled timeout=300
   become: true
```